# error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2), also strings.xml not updated

Tags: java, android, trace

I'm creating an 8 ball application and I'm using reflection to grab the strings out of the strings.xml file and in to an ArrayList but all its doing is finding the default strings in there (even the hello_world-- one which I deleted) also, I don't know how to get the string value out of the Field class that it's in.

the first System.out.println() [the amount of fields] comes out as 4.
they are all the default values of the default strings.xml file, it hasn't updated or seen the added/deleted resources.

also it's coming up with that weird trace file error

in the debugger, ansStuff is coming up with a size of 23... [the amount its suppose to be [ not 4..]] so weird

```
    Field[] ansStuff = R.string.class.getFields();
    System.out.println(R.string.class.getFields().length);
    for(Field x :ansStuff){
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x.getName());
        System.out.println(x.toString());
        if(x.getName().startsWith("ans")){
            choices.add(/*the goddamned string*/"poop");
        }
    }
```

which after taking out the debugging mess just translates to this

```
    for(Field x :R.string.class.getFields())
        if(x.getName().startsWith("ans"))
            choices.add(/*what do I add here to get the string value from the field in to the arraylist */);
```

here is the resource file

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">8ballRotate</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="ans0">It is certain</string>
<string name="ans1">It is decidedly so</string>
<string name="ans2">Without a doubt</string>
<string name="ans3">Yes – definitely</string>
<string name="ans4">You may rely on it</string>
<string name="ans5">As I see it, yes</string>
<string name="ans6">Most likely</string>
<string name="ans7">Outlook good</string>
<string name="ans8">Yes</string>
<string name="ans9">Signs point to yes</string>
<string name="ans10">Reply hazy, try again</string>
<string name="ans11">Ask again later</string>
<string name="ans12">Better not tell you now</string>
<string name="ans13">Cannot predict now</string>
<string name="ans14">Concentrate and ask again</string>
<string name="ans15">Don\'t count on it</string>
<string name="ans16">My reply is no</string>
<string name="ans17">My sources say no</string>
<string name="ans18">Outlook not so good</string>
<string name="ans19">Very doubtful</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace error message?

Comment: I cant get it out of logcat, I just looked and out of nowhere it's working... I just can't get the string data out of the field object now

Comment: All I am trying to do is get the strings out of the xml file and in to the arraylist in a generic fashion so I can add/remove strings and not worry about the code. But I am strill getting the trace error [thats the entire error, nothing else is red] but the code is working, minus the fact I can't figure out how to get the string value.

Comment: Everything is done now, thank you.